# Где хранить данные (страницы) блокнота?

Tags: c#

Хочу создать блокнот на C#. Вопрос такой: где я буду хранить заметки (страницы) блокнота? Должен иметь дело с БД, или есть альтернативный выход? Просто проблема с БД в том, что потом эти проги не запускаются на компьютерах, где нет программы БД, установленной. Остается выход - использовать БД XML, но с работой с ним я ё знаком. Кто что предложит? Я готов почитать материалы, изучить, если Вы их предложите.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону локальных легковесных СУБД типа `SQLite` или банальной сериализации.

Comment: можно использовать файловую систему как хранилище. одна заметка - один файл. Автоматически получаем древовидную структуру. Такую технику использует "блокнот" zim.

Answer (score 0):

Создай как MDI приложение.
Ну и с помощью сериализации сохраняй в файл.